# Bootstrap 3.3.7 glyphicons not working for jQueryUi 1.12

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, glyphicons

When dynamically adding two glyphicons to a jQuery UI slider button, the glyphicons are not shown. Downgrading to jQuery UI 1.10 solves the issue:

Not working: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LePopstar/yf0a201t/1/)

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>  
$('#slider a').html('<label><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></label>');
```

Working: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LePopstar/yf0a201t/)

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
$('#slider a').html('<label><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></label>');
```

Any ideas? I'd prefer not to downgrade.

Comment: Here is a working example: https://jqueryui.com/slider/#custom-handle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the proper way to use glyphicons is with `<i>` tag **(No)**
But changing `$('#slider a')` for `$('#slider span')` will work.

Cheers

Comment: `<span>` is fine.